# How can i mount fakeraid in ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount

I got gigabyte chipset with an raid support. Currently I have 2 hdd's running in raid 1.  When I was first installing ubuntu 11.04 server my fakeraid was detected, and I assigned a name for it in the initial installer and it was auto-mounted (working 100%) ever since.

However I was forced to reinstall my ubuntu server, and this part was somehow skipped in the installer.

HDD can still be seen in /dev/mapper
I can see

```
control
jmicron_GRAID -> ../dm-0
jmicron_GRAID1 -> ../dm-1
```

can you suggest me a simple way how i can auto-mount it like before? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitions to be mounted on boot are specified in `/etc/fstab`; see the `fstab(5)` man page for details.